# Converting factor to numeric

Tags: r, csv, import, type-conversion

I have a 3 million row, 500 column dataset. Although the columns are numeric, when importing from csv file, all are treated as factor, not numeric. I am trying to convert them back to numeric with the command

```
wikifixedn<-as.numeric(as.character(wikifixed))
```

wikifixed is the dataframe.

It's taking forever... My MacBook Pro, with 16GB ram and 2.3GHz Core i7 has been churning at this for more than an hour. Can I see somewhere how far along am I in the process or if the process is moving along? Is here another, faster method to deal with the conversation problem?

BTW: I tried, when importing the csv file, to force the columns to be treated as numeric using

```
> wikifixed<-read.csv('~/OneDrive/kredible/finaldata/wutao/wikipediausers.csv', header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors=F)
```

Yet, when checking I get

```
> is.numeric(wikifixed)
[1] FALSE
```

Comment: `as.numeric(levels(yourfactor))[yourfactor]` would be faster

Comment: I would use `fread` from the `data.table` package to read in. Also look at `colClasses` argument (also in `read,csv`)

Comment: worth trying `readr::read_csv('yourfile')`

Answer (score 1):

See here

https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/read.table.html

you probably should create a vector for colClasses

```
read.table(file, header = FALSE, sep = "", quote = "\"'",
       dec = ".", numerals = c("allow.loss", "warn.loss", "no.loss"),
       row.names, col.names, as.is = !stringsAsFactors,
       na.strings = "NA", colClasses = NA, nrows = -1,
       skip = 0, check.names = TRUE, fill = !blank.lines.skip,
       strip.white = FALSE, blank.lines.skip = TRUE,
       comment.char = "#",
       allowEscapes = FALSE, flush = FALSE,
       stringsAsFactors = default.stringsAsFactors(),
       fileEncoding = "", encoding = "unknown", text, skipNul = FALSE)
```

stringsAsFactors

logical: should character vectors be converted to factors? Note that this is overridden by as.is and colClasses, both of which allow finer control.

colClasses

character. A vector of classes to be assumed for the columns. Recycled as necessary, or if the character vector is named, unspecified values are taken to be NA.

Possible values are NA (the default, when type.convert is used), "NULL" (when the column is skipped), one of the atomic vector classes (logical, integer, numeric, complex, character, raw), or "factor", "Date" or "POSIXct". Otherwise there needs to be an as method (from package methods) for conversion from "character" to the specified formal class.

Note that colClasses is specified per column (not per variable) and so includes the column of row names (if any).

ALSO see here in case you want to go to data.table because you may run into more issues.

[fread in R imports a large .csv file as a data frame with one row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22316251/fread-in-r-imports-a-large-csv-file-as-a-data-frame-with-one-row)

```
require(data.table)
fread("pre2012_alldatapoints.csv", sep = ",", header= TRUE)
```

and read

the data.table FAQ at

https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki